# heat generation due to viscosity in a 3D fluid flow

Tags: thermodynamics, vector-fields, continuum-mechanics, viscosity

Consider an arbitrary 3D fluid flow:

$$\vec{\nu}=\vec{V}\left( \vec{x} ,t \right) \tag{1}$$

where velocity at each point $\vec{\nu}$ is a function $\vec{V}$  of position $\vec{x}$ and time $t$ (non-steady). Due to the viscosity $\mu$ there is heat being generated at each point in space. I know this heat should be a function of velocity, viscosity and div/curl of velocity:

$$ \dot{q}=F\left(\vec{\nabla},\vec{\nu},\mu \right) \tag{2}$$

But I can't just find it out.

For a 2D problem with unidirectional horizontal velocity of:

$$ \nu_x=V_x\left(x,y,t\right) \tag{3}$$

I think I can write

$$ \dot{q}=\mu  \frac{\partial \nu_x}{\partial y}\nu_x \tag{4}$$

Where $\tau_x=\mu \frac{\partial \nu_x}{\partial y} $ is the shear force due to viscosity. But I'm not quite sure if that's correct.

I would appreciate if you could help me know what is the correct form for equation 2.

P.S. I'm not quite sure but I think it should be something like:

$$ \dot{q}=\mu \left( \vec{\nu} \times \vec{\nabla}\right).\vec{\nu} \tag{5}$$

Answer (score 2):

It's not what you have written.  The rate of viscous heat generation per unit volume is given by $$2\mu\mathbf{E}:\mathbf{E}$$ where $\mathbf{E}$ is the rate of deformation tensor.  For the shear flow you mentioned, this reduces to $\mu (dv/dy)^2$.  See Transport Phenomena by Bird, et al for the full development.

Comment: I don't understand this notation. how should I write $E$? and what type of operator $:$ is?

Comment: $\mathbf{E}=(\nabla \mathbf{v}+(\nabla \mathbf{v})^T)/2$ (the velocity gradient tensor plus its transpose divided by 2), and $\mathbf{E}:\mathbf{E}$ is the double contraction of the rate of  deformation tensor with itself.  See the reference I provided, if you are not familiar working with tensors.

Comment: I found the book. would you be so kind to be more specific on the section I should read? I have the hardcopy of the second edition.

Comment: Appendix A covers vector and tensor analysis.  Consider particularly section A.3 which covers dyadic tensor notation and manipulation, and how to get dot products and double-dot products of tensors.

Comment: For future reference: double dot product of Tensors $A$ and $B$ if represented as matrices is defined as $\textbf{A}:\textbf{B}=a_{ij}b_{ji}$

Comment: Is $\textbf{E:E}=\left(\frac{\partial \nu_x}{\partial x}\right)^2+\left(\frac{\partial \nu_y}{\partial y}\right)^2+\left(\frac{\partial \nu_z}{\partial z}\right)^2+\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\partial \nu_x}{\partial y}+\frac{\partial \nu_y}{\partial x}\right)^2+\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\partial \nu_y}{\partial z}+\frac{\partial \nu_z}{\partial y}\right)^2+\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\partial \nu_x}{\partial z}+\frac{\partial \nu_z}{\partial x}\right)^2$ correct?

Comment: Yes.  That looks correct.

Comment: By the way, Nice Job.

Comment: Thanks. you may want to add this to the post?

Comment: I was wondering if you could help me know which section of the book refers to the equation $2\mu\mathbf{E}:\mathbf{E}$?

Comment: In Section 3.3, the book gives it as $\mathbf{\tau}:\mathbf{\nabla v}$ which is the same thing.  See Eqns. B.7 for $\Phi_v$ in cartesian, cylindrical, and spherical coordinate systems.

Comment: What is $\Phi_v$? I hope it is not $2\mu\mathbf{E}:\mathbf{E}$ otherwise what I wrote above is wrong!

Comment: It is supposed to be 2E:E.

Comment: $$\Phi_v=2\left(
\left(\frac{\partial \nu_x}{\partial x}\right)^2+
\left(\frac{\partial \nu_y}{\partial y}\right)^2+
\left(\frac{\partial \nu_z}{\partial z}\right)^2
\right)+
\left(\frac{\partial \nu_x}{\partial y}+\frac{\partial \nu_y}{\partial x}\right)^2+
\left(\frac{\partial \nu_y}{\partial z}+\frac{\partial \nu_z}{\partial y}\right)^2+
\left(\frac{\partial \nu_x}{\partial z}+\frac{\partial \nu_z}{\partial x}\right)^2-
\frac{2}{3}\left( \frac{\partial \nu_x}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial \nu_y}{\partial y}+\frac{\partial \nu_z}{\partial z} \right)^2$$

Comment: My calculation above is wrong! I also checked [this](http://rheology.tripod.com/z07.13.pdf)  happy that I realise that early before I implement some code to solve it! Thanks.

Comment: For future reference the term referring to what I'm looking for is called viscous dissipation function.

Comment: Yes.  The equation I was referring to and the dissipation function you derived in the earlier post applies to an incompressible fluid.

Comment: So to be clear equation $\mathbf{\tau}:\mathbf{\nabla v}=2\mu\mathbf{E}:\mathbf{E}$ only applies to the incompressible fluids? In my case I'm dealing with air which is of course compressible. happy that I realised that early enough.

Comment: Yes.  I guess I was biased by my background in polymer fluid mechanics where the polymer is typically assumed to be incompressible.  Of course, if I were analyzing a compressible fluid flow, I would check BSL (Transport Phenomena) first to be sure.

Comment: No problem. Happy ending: I found what I was looking for. Thanks.