# Conservation of heat equation: what represent heat, enthalpy or internal energy?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, continuum-mechanics

I'm trying to write the heat transfer equation in an arbitrary fluid (compressible and viscous). Consider an adiabatic system where the only heat generated is due to the internal friction/viscosity. In a fluid, the dissipation function is:

$$\Phi_v= \check{\tau}:\check{\nabla}^T\check{\nu} \tag{1}$$

$\boldsymbol{\tau}$ is defined as

$$\check{\tau}=\check{\sigma}-P\check{I} \tag{2}$$

Where $\boldsymbol{\sigma}$ is the Cauchy stress tensor and $P$ is the hydrostatic pressure.

Assuming that conduction and radiation are negligible, and convection is the only form of heat transfer, I think I can write the conservation of heat as:

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\left( q \right)
+\check{\nabla}\left( q \, \check{\nu}^T \right)=
 \check{\tau}: \check{\nabla}^T \check{\nu} \tag{3}$$

Now what I do not understand is which one represent heat: enthalpy $h$ or internal energy $e$? For example I'm trying to write the equation for an ideal gas. Can I use enthalpy and write the conservation of heat as:

$$ \frac{\partial}{\partial t}\left( \rho T \right)
+\check{\nabla}\left( \rho T \, \check{\nu}^T \right)=
\frac{1}{c_P} \check{\tau}:\check{\nabla}^T\check{\nu} \tag{4}$$

Or should I use the internal energy:

$$ \frac{\partial}{\partial t}\left( \rho T \right)
+\check{\nabla}\left( \rho T \, \check{\nu}^T \right)=
\frac{1}{c_{\nu}} \check{\tau}:\check{\nabla}^T\check{\nu} \tag{5}$$

Which one of the equations 4 or 5 is the correct form? Or maybe they are both wrong?

**Notation:**

- $\check{A}$ is the matrix representation of tensor $\boldsymbol{A}$
- $:$ is the the double dot product of two square matrices (i.e. $\check{A}:\check{B}=a_{ij}b_{ji}$ in Einstein notation form)
- $\check{a}^T\check{b}$ (Where $\check{a}$ and $\check{b}$ are row matrices) is the dyadic product of first rank tensors $\boldsymbol{a}$ and $\boldsymbol{b}$, usually noted as $\boldsymbol{a}\boldsymbol{b}$. Also known as outer product $ \vec{a} \otimes \vec{b}$ in vector form.
- $\check{A}\check{B}$ is the matrix multiplication and for row matrices $\check{a}\check{b}^T \equiv\vec{a}.\vec{b} $ dot product in vector form

Comment: Do you know the difference between $c_p$ and $c_v$?

Comment: yes of course. $c_P$ and $c_{\nu}$ are the specific heat capacity for isobaric and isochoric processes respectively. For an ideal gas $h=c_P T$ and $e=c_{\nu} T$

Comment: and what type of process are you describing? isobaric or isochoric?

Comment: Neither. It is an ideal gas so the equations are valid regardless of the process. see [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/384392/internal-energy-of-an-ideal-gas).

Comment: Yesterday, I referred you to BSL for the viscous dissipation.  BSL also has much more, including the derivation of the equation that you are looking for.  They start out with (a) the overall differential energy balance equation (i.e., the open system version of the first law) and (b) the mechanical energy balance equation (which is basically the equation of motion dotted with the velocity vector).  When they subtract (b) from (a), they obtain what I like to call the "thermal energy balance equation."  This is the equation you are looking for. Table 11.4-1, Eqn. I.

Comment: @ChesterMiller great to have you here. this is the follow up of [the question I asked yesterday](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/387404/heat-generation-due-to-viscosity-in-a-3d-fluid-flow). On page 340 of Transport Phenomena by Bird (ed2 2002) I found this: 

$$\rho c_\nu\frac{DT}{D t}=-\left( \check{\nabla}\check{q}^T \right) -T\left( \frac{\partial P}{\partial T}\right)_\rho \left(\check{\nabla} \check{\nu}^T \right)-\left(\check{\tau}:\check{\nabla}^T\check{\nu}\right)$$  What is the $\boldsymbol{q}$ term in that equation?

Comment: It is the heat flux vector (heat flow per unit area).  $\mathbf{q}=-k\nabla T$. You might also consider using the other form of Eqn. I given in BSL (involving Cp); your choice depends on whichever one is more convenient for solving your specific problem.

Comment: So in my case considering that conduction is negligible, it is zero. And considering that I deal with ideal gas it simplifies to :  $$\rho c_\nu\frac{DT}{D t}+P \left(\check{\nabla} \check{\nu}^T \right)+\left(\check{\tau}:\check{\nabla}^T\check{\nu}\right)=0$$

Comment: Is heat conduction really negligible in your situation?

Comment: Well, I assume. speed is high and air is a bad conductor. So I think neglecting the conduction is not far from reality.

Comment: If you have a solid boundary in your system, the viscous dissipation together with the no-slip boundary condition at the wall is going to result in a continuing increase in the boundary temperature if you don't include heat conduction.

Comment: @ChesterMiller I just had [a failed attempt solving the model using Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/166310/solving-navier-stokes-equations-for-a-steady-state-compressible-viscous-flow-in). I was wondering if you could be so kind to take a look at it.

Comment: Sorry.  Not my "thing."  Hopefully, someone else can help.

Comment: @ChesterMiller thanks. You have already helped me a lot.

Comment: In [this lecture notes](https://goo.gl/hqyxxz) page 3 equation (1.12) draws a different picture for energy balance: $$\rho \left( \frac{\partial h}{\partial t} +\check{\nabla}\left( h \check{\nu}^T \right) \right)=-\frac{D P}{D t} +\Phi_\nu$$ first of the $\Phi_\nu$ term is in the other side of the equation and secondly enthalpy is being used to represent heat as I proposed in the OP.

Comment: On page 4 of [this lecture notes](http://www.ldeo.columbia.edu/~mspieg/mmm/Conserveq.pdf) equation Eqn. (1.2.2) is exactly the Eqn. 4 I proposed in the OP. I think considering enthalpy as heat is the right answer to my question. It worth noting that $\Phi$ is here also in the right side which makes sense. viscosity generates energy increasing the enthalpy. I do not understand why in BSL it is in the different side!

Comment: On page 94 Eqn. (6.5) of [this book](https://goo.gl/4DyD7u) there is yet a different equation: $$\rho\frac{D e}{D t}=\check{\sigma}:\check{\nabla}^T\check{\nu}+r$$ so definitely the $\Phi$ term should be on the right, but I do not understand what $r$ is here!

Comment: Here https://www.cfd-online.com/Wiki/Navier-Stokes_equations#Derivation_of_the_energy_equation my interpretation is that they combine the flow velocity with the stress tensor to get work energy. Heat flux and heat generation terms for heat, one of which they rewrite using Fouriers heat law. This they equate with time rate of internal energy plus kinetic energy, followed by application of Reynolds transport theorem.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, after extensive research I think I have found the right answer to this question. Unfortunately there are a lot of different notations and some sources, such as Transport Phenomena by Bird (ed2 2002) which was suggested in the comments, are entirely different.

Firstly, the definition I wrote for viscous stress tensor is wrong. In a perfect fluid:

$$\check{\tau}=\check{\sigma}+P\check{I} \tag{6}$$

Where $\check{\sigma}$ is the cauchy stress tensor.

Secondly internal energy $e$ is heat and enthalpy $h=e+\frac{P}{\rho}$ is the total non-kinetic energy (if there is a such a term! or maybe potential energy?), the total energy is $h+\frac{1}{2}\check{\nu}\check{\nu}^T$. The detailed proof can be found in [1,2] but in the end the result is:

$$ \rho \frac{D e}{D t}=\check{\sigma}:\check{\nabla}\check{\nu} \tag{7}$$

Or in expanded form for an ideal fluid:

$$\rho\left( \frac{\partial e}{\partial t}+\left( \check{\nu}\check{\nabla}^T \right)e \right)=-P\left( \check{\nabla}\check{\nu}^T \right)+ \check{\tau}:\check{\nabla}\check{\nu} \tag{8}$$

Obviously for ideal gas $e=c_\nu T$ and $P=\rho \mathring{R} T$. I have the feeling that 8 can be derived from Eqn. 4 in the OP. But I'm not sure.

**References:**

1. Mathematical Modeling in Continuum Mechanics By Roger Temam, Alain Miranville page 94 Eqn. (6.5)
2. Introduction to continuum mechanics By Michael Lai, page 378 Eqn. (6.18.1)